# searching for a specific user name using the complete full name won't show correct results

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

We have the following issue:
If you search a specific user (for example: John Doe) using the full name: **John Doe** we get the correct result for that user in page 8 and the first 7 pages are results for people who work in the same business unit as John Doe. What is strange is if you search: **John Do** we get the result at the top of the first page, but if we either search for first name or complete full name we get the result in page 8.

Note: SharePoint 2010 enterprise SP1

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you modify the ranking?

Comment: The following article helped in troubleshooting the issue: http://www.prosharepointsearch.com/?p=152 when I used another ranking model (example: MainResultDefault) I got the expected results. Also, we are dealing with a consultant company that deployed some sort of customization and I believe that might be the issue. I did contact them to see they can figure out why we are seeing this behavior.